# My Daughter forgot her pin to unlock her screen on her tablet. help?

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out

I have an Asod 7 inch tablet. My daughter put in a password to lock the screen and can't remember what it is. How do I reset it so she can unlock and use her tablet?

Answer (score 0):

If the device is logged into a Google account, try going to [Google's Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and click "Lock". Set the password you want and push it out.

I'm not sure what OS version introduced this feature, so if its too old an OS, i don't think this will work.